# Ant+Ivy retrieves too many artifacts

Tags: java, ant, maven-2, ivy

Ivy retrieves artifacts that include "target" artifact, resulting in a huge set of artifacts. Can someone explain why is this happening, and how I can avoid that?

*build.xml:*

```
...
<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve type="jar" />
</target>
...
```

*ivy.xml:*

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-core" rev="2.7" />
</dependencies>
...
```

[Screenshot of retrieved dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va6iE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivy by default is resolving all the transitive dependencies. When you call `ivy:resolve` set `transitive` to `false` and you will get only log4j, not it's dependencies

Additionally you may want to specify some configs that you need.